# Sessions DB usage spiking, causing performance problems

Tags: xdb, session-state

I've got a problem with one of my clients' sites (Sitecore 8.0, Azure cloud services (custom deployment model)) and could really use a solution. Here's the story in bullet point form:

- Deployment of code (some by us and some by client) was Thursday last week. This deployment included some code that uses xDB, both mongoDB and reporting DB.
- Friday last week the site slowly (over the course of 3-4 hours) started to go down/become unresponsive.
- Azure monitoring showed that the sessions DB (on an Azure SQL DB instance) was nearly 100% usage (500 DTUs).
- Client IT recycled the app pools and upsized the sessions DB to 1000 DTUs. This seemed to abate the problem, though it was nearing the end of the day on Friday (and traffic was declining), so we decided to meet Monday morning to be ready in case the site acted up again.
- This morning the site started out fine, but around 10AM-11AM started to slow down.
- The sessions DB usage was climbing. When it hit about 60% DTU usage, client IT upsized the sessions DB to 1750 DTUs. We also disabled xDB.
- The site has been stable since and sessions DB usage has hovered at around 5%, but we want to know the cause.

Things I've checked so far:

- Sitecore logs don't show any obvious causes. There is a significant number of errors in the log, but nothing that seems clearly related (N.B. the client has updated the format of the log files in such a way that SCLA doesn't work with them). 
  ** There are contact errors like this one: `ERROR General error when submitting contact. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: A contact is locked by another operation.` I confirmed this is not the anonymous user (i.e. it is not the specific problem [Brian Pederson called out here](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2015/07/02/sitecore-8-and-tracker-current-session-identify-overriding-expired-contact-session-lock-for-contact-id/)). 
  ** There are Maxmind errors like this one: `ERROR Failed to perform GeoIp lookup for 70.210.74.243 Exception: Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.CannotParseResponseException Message: Unexpected format. Cannot parse the MaxMind response for IP address: 70.210.74.243`. Obviously, MaxMind is deprecated, but I don't think these are causing the problem... or are they?
- I looked at IIS logs to see if there was a surge in traffic or other interesting details. While traffic did rise significantly during the Friday outage, the traffic only appeared to be double, which probably shouldn't have been enough to cause the problems. Additionally, the traffic on Monday (today) was about the same as the previous Monday.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Is the affected site using the Inrole cache and Azure is hosted as PAAS. I would suggest moving to Redis session provider

Comment: @ABDmaverick: Azure is hosted as PAAS, not sure about cache. Sitecore support also suggested moving to Redis as well. I had suggested MongoDB as well to them, as they already have MongoDB infrastructure. Either way, I know they need to move off of SQL Server for sessions storage, but we are looking to explain the behavior.

Comment: MongoDb or SQL both are ok for sessionstate , and you are using InRoleCache on azure paas , it has serious memory leaks and MS has removed support for Inrolecache from 2016